# Which stats test to use for the following data?

Tags: self-study, spss, modeling, multiple-comparisons

A hypothetical study I am creating focuses on whether deer assess each other's fighting prowess based on their antler size.

For a sample size of 20, whereby I have all 20 deer antler measurements (this is more than one factor and will be length, width and number of points), I would like to assess different levels of interaction with other deer. To clarify, deer A who has 3 antler points, 12cm length and 3 width has 3 ignore him, 4 get within 5 metres, 6 engage in parallel walking, and the remainder engaging in full battle. I then want to compare whether this deer is approached for fights more than the remaining 19 deer, based on the different features of their antlers and the differing levels of interactions.

Does anyone know what statistics test would be best for SPSS? This paper is primarily based on animal behaviour and statistics is not a focus, but of course accuracy and insight would be great. I'm a basic statistician so simple terms would be appreciated, and please do remember I will not need to run the test, merely state what I would do.

EDIT - Through research and my statistics class notes, my current thoughts are that multinomial logistic regression might work? Or, a Spearmans Correlation?

Comment: How would such an observational study eliminate the alternative explanation that the deer are not using some other cue than antler size (which might nevertheless be correlated with it)? E.g. maybe they instead are affected by how strong the neck and shoulders look...

Comment: @Glen_b indeed, you are entirely correct. The specific question I have is:

Describe the studies you would undertake to determine how male deer use antler size and vocalisations to assess the fighting prowess of rivals.

It is widely addressed in the literature that your issue is a common one, with other confounding factors tainting the studies to date. At the moment, I can only think of the above, though will address your observation later, somehow!

Comment: As a routine textbook style question (such as might be assigned in a class) you should probably add the `self-study` tag (and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info))